# QGIS 1.8.0 does not launch

Tags: sqlite

I Installed the 1.8.0v on Win7 profesional SP1 system (as administrator) and I take this message: "The procedure entry point sqlite3_open_v2 could not be lovated in the dynamic library sqlite3.dll".
QGIS 1.7 was working.
Help